# 3d-force-graph node and sprite text

Tags: three.js

I'm using the [react version of 3d-force-graph](https://github.com/vasturiano/react-force-graph) and making some default nodes (spheres) and some sprite text nodes.  (Return false does the default sphere node)

```
       nodeThreeObject={node => {
                  if (node.id % 6 == 0){
                    const sprite = new SpriteText(buzzwords[node.id % buzzwords.length]);
                    sprite.color = "#8898aa";
                    sprite.textHeight = 12;
                    return sprite;
                  } else {
                    return false
                  }
                }}
```

I was wondering how I could add a sphere node behind my text nodes.  They look a little off without it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

simply set `nodeThreeObjectExtend` to `true`:

```
<ForceGraph3D
    graphData={graphData}
    nodeThreeObjectExtend={true}
    nodeThreeObject={node => {
        if (node.id % 6 == 0){
            const sprite = new SpriteText(buzzwords[node.id % buzzwords.length]);
            sprite.color = "#8898aa";
            sprite.textHeight = 12;
            return sprite;
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }}
```